# Xcode does not support printf_s ?

Tags: xcode, printf

Not sure why Xcode complains "Use of undeclared identifier 'printf_s' did you mean 'printf'? Try to find help from Xcode manual but not useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf_s("Line one\n\t\tLine two\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: clang doesn't have the implementation of printf_s yet , for now go with printf